# Using ParseObject in a FOR Loop

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am getting error in for(**ParseObject object**: objects) marked in bold.

I am actually trying to query images from parse and put them in a list.

This is the code I am getting error at.

Any idea why.

Thanks

```
private void readPosts() {

        // Query the Class called "ImageUpload" in Parse
        ParseQuery query  = new ParseQuery("ImageUpload");

  
        //Sort query by Ascending order as per created date
        query.orderByAscending("createdAt");

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(List objects, ParseException e) {

                if(objects.size() >0 && e == null){
                    for(ParseObject object: objects){
                        ParseFile file = (ParseFile) object.get("ImageFile");
                        file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                if(e == null && data != null){
                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
                                    imageAdded.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }else {
                    //objectRetrievalFailed();
                }
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: and what is the error you got?

Comment: It is asking me to either 
Change parameter type 'object' to 'Object' 
or
Migrate object type to Object
implementing them changed the ParseObject to Object.

Comment: Can you try with `List<ParseObject> objects` instead of `List objects`?

Comment: Yes that solved it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Just by adding this '<'ParseObject>' to public void "public void done(List<ParseObject'> objects, ParseException e)"

Thanks